# Precise scrubbing with HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: iphone, streaming, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm using HTTP Streaming for my iPhone app (as required by Apple). However, video scrubbing is noticeably imprecise. Whenever I seek to a time in the video, it jumps to the start time of the nearest segment. This occurs with both MPMoviePlayerController and AVPlayer (using seekToTime: with a tolerance of 0).

Have others encountered this issue as well? Did anyone find a way to get precise scrubbing with HTTP Live Streaming? I'm willing to go low-level if necessary. The Youtube app has precise scrubbing but I don't believe it uses HTTP Live Streaming. Can anyone confirm/deny?

*Update:* 
I'm using mediafilesegmenter with the default settings (10 sec / chunk). My master .m3u8 looks like

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=957267
http://[...].m3u8?file_urlkey=[...]
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=258157
http://[...].m3u8?file_urlkey=[...]
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=53220
http://[...].m3u8?file_urlkey=[...]
```

The individual .m3u8s look like

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXTINF:9.9988149305,
http://[...].ts?bytes=0-1195491
#EXTINF:9.9988149305,
http://[...].ts?bytes=1195492-2390983
#EXTINF:9.9988149305,
http://[...].ts?bytes=2390984-3586475
#EXTINF:9.9988149305,
http://[...].ts?bytes=3586476-4781967
#EXTINF:9.9988149305,
http://[...].ts?bytes=4781968-5977459
#EXTINF:0.345925347493,
http://[...].ts?bytes=5977460-6018819
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Thanks!

Comment: Youtube uses Progressive Download
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/blog/19578/what-is-video-streaming

Comment: Try encoding in smaller segments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeking in the middle of segments is not possible with HTTP Live Streaming -- I confirmed with an Apple rep at WWDC.

But they said that seeking precision will be improved in iOS5.

Answer (score 2):

We're using HTTP Live Streaming and scrubbling work pretty nice. What did you use to decode/segment your videos? Because I guess this is more a problem of the playlist file (the m3u8) rather than the implementation itself.

Comment: Updated the question to add more information. Do my .m3u8s look similar to yours?

Comment: Yup. And we used mediafilesegmenter too :/  Sorry couldn't help you mate

Comment: No problem, thanks for your help so far! One more question: if you seek to, e.g. 1:07 in your app, does the scrubber jump back 5-10 seconds after releasing the scrubber bar? Or is it precise to 1 or 2 seconds?